# How to sort a column based on another column to resolve can't add or update child row issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which contains `id` and `supervisorId`. `Id` is the PK and `supervisorId` is the foreign key (Self Join).

When I try to insert the data into the table, mysql throws unable to add or update a child row error. Because of relationship between two columns, I can't populate the `supervisorId` column without `Id` column.

Is there any way to insert the data in a single query?

Comment: Is supervisorId defined as NOT NULL, otherwise you could update the user later? Also it will help if you added the failing query and table definition to the question?

Comment: Supervisor I'd may be null because the person with the highest position  in the Company dont have any supervisor for one person it will be null

Comment: Why not insert supervisors first or update your users once a supervisor has been inserted? It's not clear why this has to be done in one query?

Comment: Here iam comparing two tables iam joining two tables. For example if the Id in table  A when it is not in table B iam inserting the data...if I firstly insert supervisor Id then in the next step I can't insert the ids because my condition will fail right?

Comment: Now you have 2 tables, sorry but I don't follow. Why can't you post your query/queries and explain what the issue is with them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the rows in two steps:

1. Insert the rows without supervisors (i.e. `supervisor_id = NULL`.
2. Then update the rows with the correct supervisor, when you know their ids.

It is not clear how you are processing the data.  If you are trying to move rows from one table to another, you should probably ask *another* question, with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish.